# nHibernate , Linq Operand Exception

Tags: linq, hibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I m getting the error 'Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'Boolean' and 'String'' when i m trying to filtering the data in the grid with datetime column. i m using jqgrid and fluent nhibernate.

```
                return session.Query<User>().Where(filterExpression).Count();
```

on the above code i m getting the exception for search according to date time and for bool tpye also.

Does anyone knows what is the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell us more about `filterExpression`? What you have so far looks correct, but expression trees are easy to get wrong.

Comment: filterExpression value is  `CreationDate = "7/11/2011 12:00:00 AM"`

Comment: The Exception is coming on LinqExtension.cs file

Comment: How do you construct the `filterExpression` expression tree?

Comment: 'return String.Format("{0} {1} \"{2}\"", searchField, searchOper, DateTime.Parse(searchValue));' this return the filterexpression.

Comment: Shouldn't `filterExpression` have type `Expression<Func<User, bool>>`, something like `u => u.CreationDate == "7/11/2011 12:00:00 AM"`?

Comment: No.. :S.. can u give an example ?